# Private chat system MYSQL query ORDERBY and GROUPBY

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating private message system in php/mysql.

I created message tables:

```
messages(message_id|sender_id|receiver_id|message_text|created_time)
```

Here is data in table

```
message_id|sender_id||receiver_id|message_text|   created_time
   1         101          102       Message A    2012-06-07 08:07:18
   2         101          102       Message B    2012-06-07 08:10:20
   3         103          102       Message C    2012-06-07 08:12:43
```

The output I want is:

```
     sender_id|message_text |   created_time
       101      Message B     2012-06-07 08:10:20
       103      Message C     2012-06-07 08:12:43
```

Something like:

```
SELECT sender_id,message_text,created_time from messages
WHERE receiver_id='102'
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDERBY BY created_time
```

I want to show the last message of any user.

Comment: Mmmh so what is your question?

Comment: @EdouardMoinard, in my question its written "The output I want is:"

Comment: Oh sorry I missread your db I thought your query was good... My bad ^^

Comment: Please check @Arion answer. Its working. I have added link as Demo there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sender_id, MESSAGE_TEXT, created_time
FROM messages
WHERE receiver_id = 102
  AND created_time IN
    (SELECT MAX(created_time)
     FROM messages
     GROUP BY sender_id);
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/183e7/5)

Comment: I extended my question if you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941763/private-chat-system-mysql-query-to-display-last-message-of-sender-receiver

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    messages.sender_id,
    messages.message_text,
    messages.created_time
FROM
    messages
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(created_time) AS LatestCreated,
                t.sender_id
            FROM
                messages AS t
            GROUP BY
                t.sender_id
        ) AS Latest
        ON Latest.sender_id=messages.sender_id
        AND Latest.LatestCreated=messages.created_time
WHERE
    messages.receiver_id=102
ORDER BY
    messages.created_time
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/183e7/1)

Comment: I think your answer is quite near to solution. But the problem I am facing with you answer is: if there is 2 messages from a same sender then it works ok but if 3 then not grouping sender_id.

Comment: @With three answer it is also working. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ce0/1) Else can you edit the sqlfiddle in input and provide the link??

Comment: Oo fahim, thanks for this. Really appreciate. yes it is working correctly. where I made mistake is I copy data of already existed row and dint changed time. The only problem is coming if created_time have same time value.

Comment: :) this mistake happen very often :) :D

Answer (score -1):

You were close - you typed 'ORDER BY' as 'ORDERBY BY'. You'll get the correct data with the WHERE clause you already have. You also need to order your date in descending order to show the newest first (as below).

I can see that you're asking to aggregate the data in some way, but I don't quite understand *why* as each row's unique.

### Solution

```
SELECT sender_id, message_text, created_time FROM messages
WHERE receiver_id = 102
ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

Comment: Thanks james for you answer. But your query will give me all 3 rows in table with orderby time. I am looking for groupby as well.

Comment: So - you only want to show the last message per sender? Your intention is to hide previously sent messages?

Comment: Yes right as explained in my question. I want only latest message received.