# Private chat system MYSQL query to display last message of sender/receiver

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here I am extending my previous question.

[Private chat system MYSQL query ORDERBY and GROUPBY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929366/private-chat-system-mysql-query-orderby-and-groupby)

In addition, I created one more table called users from where I will get users info.

messages table

```
  message_id|sender_id||receiver_id|message_text|   created_time
    1         101          102       Message A    2012-06-07 08:07:18
    2         101          102       Message B    2012-06-07 08:10:20
    3         103          102       Message C    2012-06-07 08:12:43
```

users table:

```
 id  | name
 101   bob
 102   jack
 103   mark
```

Now finally I am able to get following results:

```
      name|message_text |  created_time
      mark   message C    2012-06-07 08:12:43
      bob    message B    2012-06-07 08:10:20
```

By using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages,users
WHERE messages.receiver_id = 102
AND messages.sender_id=users.id
AND messages.created_time IN
(SELECT MAX(created_time)
FROM messages
GROUP BY sender_id)
ORDER BY messages.created_time DESC
```

Now what I want in my result is

if jack(id:102) reply to mark(id:103) then how can I get this output:

```
      name|message_text |  created_time
      mark   message D    2012-06-07 08:12:48
      bob    message B    2012-06-07 08:10:20
```

NOTE:HERE "MESSAGE D" AND TIME STAMP IS OF JACK WHICH HE REPLIED TO MARK.

where message_text field will display the last message between mark and jack
created_time field will show message created time
and name field will show the name of person to whom jack is sending or receiving messages.

I am thinking we need to modify/split tables but don't know how and what query will do this task.

Comment: I don't see `message D` in your table

Comment: @Jadzia is this a group messaging system?

Comment: and if `jack` replies to `mark` sender of the `message D` should be `jack` I guess?

Comment: @Jack what D R is saying is correct. If jack is replying then message D will be of jack.

Comment: D R if you see chat system in sites like badoo.com and tagged.com. They are using the chat system what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is basically to group by thread rather than sender. Threads can be initiated between two people, regardless of being sender / receiver.

To accomplish this, I would recommend changing your data structure similar to what's been discussed here: [Is there a simpler way to achieve this style of user messaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588391/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-achieve-this-style-of-user-messaging/10740169#10740169)

Comment: Yess! I was looking for something like this. Let me try it..:)

Comment: all right jack so i created all tables as you said. Now what query will give me the result i wanted?

Comment: @Jadzia the thread is full of queries that should give you an idea of how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a group chat don't limit to a receiver_id like `messages.receiver_id = 102`

```
SELECT users.name,
       temp.MESSAGE_TEXT,
       temp.created_time
FROM
  (SELECT sender_id, MESSAGE_TEXT, created_time
   FROM messages
   WHERE created_time IN
       (SELECT MAX(created_time)
        FROM messages
        GROUP BY sender_id)) AS temp
LEFT JOIN users ON temp.sender_id = users.id;
```

show last message each sender sent

Comment: D R thanks again for reply. But this is off course limited to receiver_id. If you can have u look on what jack is saying. this i want but still query is problem there.

Comment: Actually query I am looking will be summary page of all messages. if you want i can make a demo graphics for u...

Comment: yes u better update your question. someone will answer. sorry! I'm little busy right now..

Answer (score 0):

json in table frist Tbl_meessage and  table users

Tbl_meessage filds
idmessage sender     receiver   message

table users filds
id name family

use query and group by in delete message repeat

solution
sender->id receiver->id  or sender id

for example
query select
Tbl_message.sender=1   Tbl_receiver=2   or   Tbl_message.sender=2  Tbl_receiver=1

full query sql

SELECT Tbl_meessage.idmessage,Tbl_meessage.sender,Tbl_meessage.receiver,Tbl_meessage.message,users.id,users.name,users.family FROM Tbl_meessage INNER JOIN users ON users.id=Tbl_meessage.receiver and Tbl_meessage.sender="+sender+" and Tbl_meessage.receiver="+receiver+" or Tbl_meessage.receiver="+sender+" and Tbl_meessage.sender="+receiver+" GROUP BY Tbl_meessage.idmessage

tip
The user can see his own message but it may be with someone else's message sender. To solve this problem, the "or" command was used.

good luck.